# AUTOHOTKEY Hotstrings with overlapping abbreviations

Tags: autohotkey

I wish to create a hotstring "@@" for my email address, and another "@@@" for my full postal address. I have created a script that works when the third hotstring character differs from the second, but can't get it to work for my preferred "@@@" hotstring.

My working example uses "@@" for the email, and "@@1" for address, where the "1" needs to be entered within 0.7 seconds of entering "@@":

```
:*:@@::
keywait 1, D T 0.7
if errorlevel = 1
{
send {backspace}mrbenn@hotmail.com
}
else 
Send, {backspace}Mr.Benn, 52 Festive Road, London
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have to work out why this answer works, but it appears to work as wished for:

```
:*:@@::
keywait @, U T 0.7
keywait @, D T 0.7
if errorlevel = 1
{
send {backspace}mrbenn@hotmail.com
}
else 
Send, {backspace}Mr.Benn, 52 Festive Road, London
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Something to bear in mind is that the asterisk in the first set of colons means to not wait for an end character, like space or return  to fire (see docs https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm for full list).

A more elegant solution might be something like:

```
::@@::myemail@somedomain.com
:*:@@@::Mr Random, 123 Some St, Anytown, 012345
```

I personally prefer using a prefix character in my hotstrings like "*" when sending a full string and not just a typo fix. Example:

```
:*:*tysm::thank you so much
```

In my decade of experience with AHK this prevents accidentally creating a hotstring that replaces something you didn't think about on initially writing the script (something always gets forgotten).